# WebService Post is working on emulator but not on device

Tags: c#, android, web-services, ssl, xamarin

I'm trying to POST data to a WebService with SSL Certification.
It's working fine in Emulator but the Device is keeping stuck on `GetResponseAsync()`. I tried it with HttpClient with and without ModernHttpClient-Library but it stuck on `PostAsync()`, so it doesn't work too.

One Solution i tried of another Thread is just to add

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
        (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

^but it's also not working

In Manifest i added Permissions for Internet.

Thats the Code with `GetResponseAsync()`

```
    public async Task<Response<V>> CallWebServiceAsync<T, V>(string ticket, string url, T requestData)
    {
        try
        {
            var request = new Request<T>
            {
                Ticket = ticket,
                Data = requestData
            };

            DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(request.GetType(), this._knownTypes);

            var httpRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
            httpRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            httpRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

            var requestStream = await httpRequest.GetRequestStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            serializer.WriteObject(requestStream, request);

            var response = await httpRequest.GetResponseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            var resultStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            if (resultStream == null)
            {
                throw new FailedWebServiceInteractionException($"Got no response stream from request. URL:{url}");
            }

            var jsonResponseSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Response<V>), this._knownTypes);

            Response<V> result = (Response<V>)jsonResponseSerializer.ReadObject(resultStream);

            resultStream.Dispose();
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new FailedWebServiceInteractionException("Deserialization from json response failed", e);
        }
    }
```

Code with `PostAsync()` (+- ModernHttpClient)

```
    public async Task<Response<V>> CallWebServiceAsync<T, V>(string ticket, string url, T requestData)
    {
        try
        {
            var request = new Request<T>
            {
                Ticket = ticket,
                Data = requestData
            };

            var httpClientHandler = new NativeMessageHandler
            {
                UseDefaultCredentials = true
            };

            var httpRequest = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler)
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri(url)
            };

            httpRequest.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            httpRequest.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);

            var response =
                await
                    httpRequest.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
                        .ConfigureAwait(false);

            var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response<V>>(jsonString);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new FailedWebServiceInteractionException("Deserialization from json response failed", e);
        }
    }
```

I don't know if the certificates are the problem or something else.
They're not self-signed.

Comment: have you get any solution on this? i am experiencing the same issue.

Comment: posted solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Time is gone since then. I don't know the exact solution but here is my code that works fine now:

```
var request = new Request<T>
            {
                Ticket = ticket,
                Data = requestData
            };

            var httpClientHandler = new OkHttpClientHandler
            {
                UseDefaultCredentials = true,
                AllowAutoRedirect = true,
                AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate,
                ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Automatic
            };

            var client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler)
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri(url),
                Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15)
            };

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


            var jsonRequest = this.SerializeToJson(request);

            var compressedRequest = StringCompressor.CompressString(jsonRequest);
            var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url)
            {
                Content = new ByteArrayContent(compressedRequest)
                {
                    Headers = {ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json")}
                }
            };

            var httpResponse = await client.SendAsync(httpRequest, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            client.Dispose();
            httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            var compressedResponse = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            httpResponse.Dispose();

            var jsonResponse = StringCompressor.DecompressString(compressedResponse);

            var jsonResponseSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Response<V>), this._knownTypes);
            Response<V> result;
            using (var jsonResponseStream = this.GenerateStreamFromString(jsonResponse))
            {
                result = (Response<V>) jsonResponseSerializer.ReadObject(jsonResponseStream);
            }

            return result;
```

I'm using a self compiled wrapper of OkHttpClient library. I think ModernHttpClient (it is referencing OkHttp too) works too. Someone needs to test it.

Important to know is any other project that references this project need the library too.

- App.Base Project - Implemented the above code to connect to
  Webservice
- App Project - References to App.Base. Need the library
  too.